# Rest Controller response Page<ObjectDto> returning empty object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, httpresponse, spring-restcontroller

I have used Spring Data Pageable to implement paging and sorting. My relevant code snippet is:

```
    //GET API designed as POST due to Request Body, in lines of ES APIs
    @PostMapping(value = "/v2")
    public Page<ObjectDto> getObjects(@RequestBody @Valid Map<Integer, FilterRequestDto> filterDtoMap, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<ObjectDto> objectDtos = myService.getDtos(filterDtoMap, pageable);
        log.info(String.valueOf(objectDtos.getTotalElements()));
        return objectDtos;
    }
```

Although I have data(confirmed from the log), the above API is responding with **{}**.

However, when I am returning List like in this snippet:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/v2")
    public List<ObjectDto> getObjects(@RequestBody @Valid Map<Integer,FilterRequestDto> filterDtoMap, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<ObjectDto> objectDtos = myService.getDtos(filterDtoMap, pageable);
        log.info(String.valueOf(objectDtos.getTotalElements()));
        return objectDtos.getContent();
    }
```

Response for List return type for the exact same API is a proper response as expected:

**[
    {
        "sellingPrice": 23000,
        "id": 1,
        "version": 1,
        "createdOn": "25 Feb 2019,05:53",
        "lastUpdatedOn": "25 Feb 2019,05:53"
    }
]**

Repository Code:

```
@Repository
public interface MyObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObject, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyObject> {}
```

Service Code:

```
public Page<ObjectDto> getTyres(Map<Integer, FilterRequestDto> filterDtoMap, Pageable pageable) {
        List<FilterDto> filterDtoList = filtersService.getAllFiltersById(filterDtoMap.keySet());
        return objectMapper.toDto(myObjectRepository.findAll(ObjectSpecs.filter(filterDtoList, filterDtoMap), pageable));
    }
```

As far as I know, we can return page as a Rest API response, so what can be the issue here? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you add code of service and repository so it can be more clear

Comment: Shared the same.

Comment: can you please add code for `objectMapper.toDto`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Page<ObjectDto>` as return type of rest methods. This Page is not for that.
use return type as **`List<ObjectDto>`**

and in log you are printing

```
log.info(String.valueOf(objectDtos.getTotalElements()));
```

so its printing properly, if you return `objectDtos.getTotalElements()` in rest method  then it will also work